# ODE on unit sphere $S^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$$
\theta_t=\cos\theta+\mu
$$
where we think of $\theta\in S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

---

When I see it right, $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ means that we are identifying the real line with $S^1$? So this is an ODE which is original defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but we think of it as happening on the unit sphere?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already noticed this but the important point is that the vector field, here $f(\theta)=\cos(\theta)+\mu$, is well-defined on the quotient space, i.e. that $f(\theta+2\pi k)=f(\theta)$ is independent of $k$. This generalizes to e.g. $\dot{x}=f(x)$ on $M={\Bbb R}^d /(2\pi {\Bbb Z})^d$ as long as $f(x+2\pi n)=f(x)$ where $n\in {\Bbb Z}^d$. Many other generalizations are possible.

Comment: Does $\theta\in S^1$ mean that $\theta(t)\in S^1$ or how is this supposed to mean? From where to where is the function $\theta$ mapping?

Comment: It means that $\Theta(t)\in S^1={\Bbb R}/2\pi{\Bbb Z}$. It's a real value modulo $2\pi$ (like the angle in a circle). In practical computations you use a standard real variable. If $\Theta(t)$ is then a real valued solution the so is $\Theta(t)+2\pi k$ (any integer $k$). Does it make sense?

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you very much! Another question: If $\lvert\mu\rvert <1$, we have two equilibria on $S^1$, one stable, one unstable. With respect to the system on the real line, does this mean that we have infinitely many stable and unstable equilibria on the real line?

Comment: Yes indeed! you will have them at every value $+ 2\pi k$.

Comment: Okay, then I think I got the concept. Thanks again!